# Having trouble writing LINQ to SQL Query while storing database data into C# object classes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to store database data into C# classes and write queries using this data. However, when I write my query using LINQ to SQL, I cannot seem to figure out how to have it return just one of the columns in my class. When I execute the query as just "product", as opposed to "product.Description", it queries for all columns that exist in the C# class Product. The following code is giving me the red squigglies over the query and the error says

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<string>` to `System.Linq.IQueryable<OnlineOrderingWebPage<Product>>`.
>   An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?

```
string connStr =
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FinalProjectConnectionString"].ToString();
DataContext db = new DataContext(connStr);
Table<Product> tProduct = db.GetTable<Product>();

IQueryable<Product> custQuery =
from product in tProduct
where product.Description == "Black Bean"
select product.Description;

foreach (Product product in custQuery)
{
    lblTest.Text = ("Product: " + product.ProductID.ToString() +
        " Description: " + product.Description);
}
```

What I am working on is a shopping cart application that retrieves product information from different store locations, allowing customers to select products based on the store they select. Can someone please help guide me in the right direction as to how to fix this error.

I am really just trying to make sure that everything is working correctly with my connection and query. I just want to be able to query certain columns within the tables as opposed to the whole product object.

When I run the application with "select product", I get the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String" on the foreach line of code.

Comment: If you know that `product.Description == "Black Bean"`, why do you need to query it. It will just return `"Black Bean"`.

Comment: looks like you are just selecting the `product.Description` when you want the whole `product`. You probably have a list of strings not products

Answer (score 1):

You should specify that the table is of type Product:

```
Table<Product> tProduct = db.GetTable<Product>();
```

Then, use the var keyword for your custQuery, and select product since you want the Product objects, not just their Description:

```
var custQuery = from product in tProduct
where product.Description == "Black Bean"
select product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the last line of your LINQ statment

```
IQueryable<Product> custQuery =
    from product in tProduct
    where product.Description == "Black Bean"
    select product.Description;   <== this line
```

The `select` statement will return an `IEnumerable<T>` of the type you have specified. In this case it is returning an `IEnumerable<string>` because `Product.Description` is a `string`. You can verify this by changing your `IQueryable<Product>` to `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you want to return all `Product`'s that have a description of "Black Bean" then simply change the `select product.Description` to `select product`

```
var custQuery =
    from product in tProduct
    where product.Description == "Black Bean"
    select product;
```

If you check the debugger/editor, `custQuery` is of type `IEnumerable<Product>`.

It is also good practice to use `var` as the return type instead of `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: When I change this to select product and run the application, I get the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String" on the foreach line of code. Maybe my foreach code is the problem??

Comment: Is the `Product.Description` property of type `string`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is this the problem?

Comment: I suspect it is one of the other properties on your `Product` class not matching the field type in your table. A quick search for the error message shows lots of solutions. I suggest you try that and create a new question if you are unable to find a solution :-)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are only selecting the description, the result is not of type `IQueryable<Product>`. Just use `var` instead. Then, you can change it to the real type with the `Make explicit` refactoring, if you want.

```
var custDescriptions =
    from product in tProduct
    where product.Description == "Black Bean"
    select product.Description;
```

Here, you probably get a `IQueryable<string>` but in other cases you might get quite complex types like `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, 'a>>`. Then `var` is very handy.